# Lebesgue measurable function, positive everywhere, has integral zero

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Suppose $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue-measurable function. Also suppose that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$. Is it possible that $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = 0$?

Comment: Probably not but looking forward to see a vigorous proof! I was thinking somewhere along approximating f using simple functions, and showing that $\int f \, dm >0$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Or if we assume that $f$ is Riemann integrable, then it's even more trivial to show that the result is false.

Comment: No it is not possible otherwise $m(f>\tfrac1n))\leq n\int^1_0f=0$ for all $n$ and so $m(f>0)\leq m\big(\bigcup_n\{f>\tfrac1n\}\big)\leq\sum_m m(\{f>\tfrac1n\})=0$

Comment: It is not possible. In general, if $(X, F, \mu)$ is a measure space and $f \colon X \to [0, \infty]$ is measurable, then $\int_{X}f\,d\mu = 0$ if and only if $f = 0$ $\mu$-a.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. Consider the sets $E_n = \{x \in [0,1]: f(x) > 1/n\}$. Since $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ we can write
$$[0,1] = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n.$$
Since $\lambda([0,1]) = 1 > 0$ there must exist a $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lambda(E_{m}) > 0$. Now notice that
$$\int_{[0,1]} f \;d\lambda \geq \int_{E_{m}} f \;d\lambda \geq\int_{E_{m}}\frac{1}{m} = \frac{\lambda(E_m)}{m} > 0$$